# How to implement object specific methods?

Tags: java, method-declaration

I'm playing around with a Java game, and I'm currently trying to implement a Menu system. I have a `Menu` class and `MenuBox` class, what i'd like to do is have an abstract method in the `MenuBox` class that i would define somewhere else in the code since every `MenuBox` can have a different effect (pause/unpause game, open a different menu, change options, save game ect...).

So far I've added an Interface called `Clickable`, and it only has the method `activate()` in it which is defined as empty in the `MenuBox` class, and i'd like to redefine it when making a Menu object. Is this even possible ? I've been researching and only found dead ends but the questions were not exactly the same as mine so i'm not sure whether this is possible or if i need a completely different approach.

Here are the interface and MenuBox class:

```
public interface Clickable {
    public abstract void activate();
}

public class MenuBox implements Clickable{
    private String label;
    private int x,y,width,height;
    public MenuBox(String label,int x,int y,int width,int heigth){
        this.label = label;
        this.x = x;
        this.y =y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=heigth;
    }
    public void activate() {
        //Empty method to redefine outside the class i.e. after instantiation
    }
}
```

Comment: Methods cannot be *object-specific* they belong to a class and any specificity should be handled via properties (class variables).  You can have child classes that **inherit** from a base class and define/redefine its methods.

Comment: So there is no way around creating a subclass for every kind of button (which is a lot but only differs in the reaction to click) ?(thanks for the quick answer :) )

Comment: You can use *anonymous inner-classes* or (in case of Java 8 or higher) *lambdas*.  Read up on ***functional interfaces***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `MenuBox` class an abstract class

```
public interface Clickable {
    public abstract void activate();
}

public abstract class MenuBox implements Clickable{
    private String label;
    private int x,y,width,height;
    public MenuBox(String label,int x,int y,int width,int heigth){
        this.label = label;
        this.x = x;
        this.y =y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=heigth;
    }
}
```

Then when you want to instanciate a new MenuBox you can define the abstract method

```
MenuBox m = new MenuBox("",0,1,0,1){

    public void activate(){
        System.out.print("activated");
    }

};

m.activate();
```

Comment: Yes ! this is exactly what i was looking for ! Thanks a lot sir or madam.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a class in the MenuBox constructor to delegated the action of the activate() method. Something like this:

```
public class MenuBox implements Clickable{
    private String label;
    private int x,y,width,height;

    private ActionClass action;

    public MenuBox(String label,int x,int y,int width,int heigth, ActionClass action){
        this.label = label;
        this.x = x;
        this.y =y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=heigth;

        this.action = action;
    }

    public void activate() {
        this.action.activate();
    }
}
```

ActionClass is an interface and you can have differente implementation of it being injected in different scenarios when activate() method has different behaviors.